# Make the reputation deducted for receiving a down-vote proportional to a user's overall reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, down-votes

I feel that users with high reputation gets up-voted more even if their answer is not as complete as another with less reputation because of their reputation. I do not have any problem with that. In fact, I believe that these users have the right to be respected for their contribution to SO.

The only problem I see is when a user with high reputation gets down-voted and his reputation lowers equally to someone with low reputation. Should a down-vote lower a user's reputation proportionately to the amount of reputation that user has?

> #### Related:
>
> [Senior Members Stealing Answers and Out-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/senior-members-stealing-answers-and-out-voting)

Comment: "I feel that users with high reputation gets up-voted more even if their answer is not as complete as another with less reputation because of their reputation" - Do you have any proof to support this hypothesis?  Examples, statistical analysis, anything other than a gut feeling?

Comment: @Tom: he can't possibly have any "proof" since it's not measurable.

Comment: @Tom: anyway, I believe he is right. For example usually if two people answer my question and both answers are similar (or, as it happened once, exactly the same) I usually accept the answer of the user with the most rep.. I don't know why, I just feel the need to do it. With all that being said, I don't like this proposal, sorry partial!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of statical data on the matter. I can remove this statement for being suggestive. Unless it can contribute to a discussion.

Comment: @Kop: No probem Kop! This is only suggestion after all! :D

Comment: You're welcome to start discussions on Meta, downvotes only mean that someone disagrees with your concept.

Comment: @Tom seriously? He has a rating of 139 do you know of anyone with that low of a rating who has access to the statistical tools to pull this data or are you just being a jerk?

Comment: @Kop when the same happens to me, I feel the need to vote for the person with the lowest vote with the hopes that it will keep people interested in the site and keep coming back.  Why people refuse to support new members is beyond me.

Comment: I believe this has been discussed before...

Answer (score 3):

We don't want to start a progressive rep tax on SO.  The rep is for the quality of questions and answers, not for who gives them.  Vote the post, not the person.

Comment: Is it possible that other users up-vote another user more simply because of the person's reputation?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that happens, but I don't think it's the norm.  It actually doesn't matter then either, because it just gives incentive to the low-rep user to work harder to make better/quicker answers and get more rep, so that he can take advantage of that situation.

Comment: Just like with taxes in the real world, if you penalize people for success, you stifle their motivation.

Comment: Maybe my previous comment should be seperated completely from my question and the subject of a complete different post.

Comment: Do some searching it's probably been discussed before.

Comment: I do not want to penalize people for success. On the contrary, I believe that new users of SO are penalize compared to users that have higher reputation.

Comment: @partial, Yes, but the dynamic of success begetting success is well known out there.  This helps stimulate people to learn to be successful, because it's gives them even more incentive.  Every user on here started with 1 rep, and worked their way up to where they are, so everybody else knows that they can do it.

Comment: @partial, Also new voters arrive every day who don't give a rip about other's rep, so I think it becomes less of an issue all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no way to measure this, but I can offer my personal experiences.

All other things being equal, I will accept the user with the lower rep, an an attempt to encourage that user to continue to participate in the community.  Of course, this is really just a tie-breaker; the number one criteria for deciding the accepted answer is correctness/completeness.  Also, if one correct answer comes in long before another, equally correct answer, the first one wins.