# Are members with high reputations getting more votes by others?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Senior Members Stealing Answers and Out-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/senior-members-stealing-answers-and-out-voting)
>   [The Problem with Reputation:  Does High Reputation Attract Too Many ‘Up-Votes’?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes)

Is it possible that users up-vote other users more simply because a person has a higher reputation? If this is the case, should there be certain measures applied to counteract this, or to inform users?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-up-votes

Comment: @partial the problem is that it would take the senior members to institute such a change.  Too much emphasis is put on the number next to their name and less on the quality of their answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be putting the effect before the cause.  Users get high reputation by giving lots of good answers.  Don't be surprised when a user who has demonstrated a pattern of leaving good answers gets lots of upvotes for continuing that pattern.

Comment: +1 because you have the most rep of everyone who answered this question. ;-P

Comment: Does that mean that all their answers are good?

Comment: @partial: Definitely not, but I would expect a high proportion of them to be.

Answer (score 2):

We should educate those coming in, that the purpose of voting is to rate the answer or question.  Actually, I think this is already in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Education is the key.

You might come up with a modification of the FAQ that would help explain this better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not at a large enough level to worry about. Except on Meta where Jon Skeet gets upvotes just for being Jon Skeet at this stage. But meta rep means nothing anyway.

Comment: The Jon Skeet fanboyism is getting really old.

Comment: @Ether  This was a comment on it, not actual fanboyism

Comment: +1 for mentioning Jon Skeet